# Ctrl-G doesn't show column in Nvim

Tags: statusline

I have both vim and nvim using the same configuration file (basically nvim's config is a symlink to vim's one) but vim shows current column when I press Ctrl-G, while nvim doesn't.

Is there some configuration which is enabled by default in vim but not in nvim?

On the picture below nvim is on top, vim is on bottom.
[image: nvim is on top, vim is on bottom]

Answer (score 2):

Setting `noruler` makes the trick.